# Look Behind Regex Assertion to Match Nested HTML Table

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm looking to match a specific table within a table. Here's the sample html and a summary of my failed attempts thus far:

```
<table id="parent">
    <table class="possible_target">
            <tr><td>We're tageting this table</td></tr>
    </table>
</table>
<table class="possible_target">
    <tr><td>We're not targeteing this table</td></tr>
</table>
```

Here was my initial attempt. But even if it worked, it would likely match the second, unnested table as well:

```
~(?=<table.*?)<table class="possible_target".*?</table>~si
```

Here is my sudo expression for what I'm trying to accomplish. It would assert the presence of an opening table tag as well as the absence of a closing table tag before making the match:

```
~(?=<table.*?)(?!</table>)<table class="possible_target".*?</table>~si
```

Comment: What language are you using ?

Comment: I could plop down a regex if your language supports recursion. Looks like PCRE/Perl ?

Comment: Is it php you're working with? Curious :-)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I'm using PHP so a PCRE expression is what I'm trying to build.

Comment: @BrandonBuster Could there be multiple "possible targets" in the parent table ?

Comment: Thanks for asking. Yes, I'd like to be able to account for multiple child tables with the "possible_targets" class

Comment: Should have mentioned in my above comment, if multiple "possible_target" tables in the parent table, each would match. But if we need to keep things simple, even an expression assuming only a single "possible_target" child would be incredibly helpful. Thanks again for all the prompt feedback I've had on this thread.

Answer (score 2):

I found that interesting, as it's challenging to work with regex and nested html-tags.

My attempt does (should do) the following:

1.) Enumerate the tables by depth using a callback function. Lowest depth = 1

```
// html stuff to process
$source = "your input";

// specify tag to match
$rx_tag = "table";

// match all $rx_tag in depth (lowest = 1)
$rx_depth = 2;

// ----------------------------

// set markers using callback function
$source = preg_replace_callback('~<(/)?'.$rx_tag.'~i','set_tag_depth',$source);

function set_tag_depth($out)
{
  global $tag_depth;

  if($out[1]=="/") {
    $tag_depth--; return $out[0].($tag_depth+1);
  }

  $tag_depth++; return $out[0].$tag_depth;
}

#echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($source));
```

2.) Tables are now renamed to depth e.g. `<table2 ... </table2>` for all tables inside `<table1, <table3 ... </table3>` for tables inside `<table2` and so on. Now it's easy to match the tables in the desired depth. Then strip the enumeration, in case you need the original source again.

```
// get specified tags in desired depth
$pattern = '~<'.$rx_tag.(string)$rx_depth.'.*</'.$rx_tag.(string)$rx_depth.'>~Uis';
preg_match_all($pattern,$source,$out);

// strip markers
if(!empty($out[0]))
{
  foreach($out[0] AS $v)
  {
    $v = preg_replace('~(</?'.$rx_tag.')\d+~i','\1',$v);

    // test output
    echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($v))."<br>------------------------------<br>";
  }
}

$source = preg_replace('~(</?'.$rx_tag.')\d+~i','\1',$source);
```

It's intended, that if a tag contains tags of the same kind, those are not stripped from the parent e.g. `<table2>...</table2`> might contain `<table3>...</table3> ... <table3>...</table3>`. Set `$rx_depth = 3;` to get those.

I hope it works as it should, was very tired already :-) It's designed to work with any kinds of tags, but didn't test it much. At least an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Its problamatic searching for balanced text with parent/sibling tags with the same name,
that differ only in attributes.

That said, you could gather all potential parent candidates balanced tags in one pass.
Then search the candidates for '*possible targets*' in another pass.

Requires  2 almost identical regexes ( differing by attribute only ).
See the expanded regexes (bottom) for details.

**PHP sample code**

```
// PHP sample code

 $html = 
 '
 <table id="parent">
    <table class="possible_target">
        C table data
    </table>
    <table class="possible_target">
        D table data
    </table>
 </table>

 <table id="parent">
   <table>
     <table class="possible_target">
              <tr><td>We\'re targeting this table</td></tr>
     </table>
   </table>
 </table>

 <table class="possible_target">
     <tr><td>We\'re not targeteing this table</td></tr>
 </table>
 '
 ;

 // Regexes -
 $rx_Parent = '~(?s)<table\s+id="parent">((?<Table_Core>(?:(?>(?:(?!</table\s*>|<table[\s>][^>]*(?<!/)>).)*)|(?<New_Table><table(?!\s+id="parent">)[\s>][^>]*(?<!/)>(?&Table_Core)</table\s*>))*))</table\s*>~';
 $rx_Target = '~(?s)<table\s+class="possible_target">((?<Table_Core>(?:(?>(?:(?!</table\s*>|<table[\s>][^>]*(?<!/)>).)*)|(?<New_Table><table(?!\s+class="possible_target">)[\s>][^>]*(?<!/)>(?&Table_Core)</table\s*>))*))</table\s*>~';

 // Match all possible parent candidates -
 if ( preg_match_all ( $rx_Parent, $html, $ParentMatches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER ) )
 {
    print "\n============================\n";
    print_r( $ParentMatches[0] );
    print "\n\n";

    foreach( $ParentMatches[0] as $parent )
    {
        // Match each individual parent candidate possible targets -
        if ( preg_match_all ( $rx_Target, $parent, $TargetMatches, PREG_SET_ORDER ) )
        {
            print "\n-----------------\n>Found Valid Parent\n";
            foreach( $TargetMatches as $target )
            {
                print "Target:\n'" . $target[0] . "'\n";   // group 0
                print "Core = \n'" . $target[1] . "'\n";   // group 1
            }
        }
    }
 }
 else
 {
    print "No parents\n";
 }
```

**Output >>**

```
 ============================
 Array
 (
     [0] => <table id="parent">
    <table class="possible_target">
        C table data
    </table>
    <table class="possible_target">
        D table data
    </table>
 </table>
     [1] => <table id="parent">
   <table>
     <table class="possible_target">
              <tr><td>We're targeting this table</td></tr>
     </table>
   </table>
 )



 -----------------
 >Found Valid Parent
 Target:
 '<table class="possible_target">
        C table data
    </table>'
 Core = 
 '
        C table data
    '
 Target:
 '<table class="possible_target">
        D table data
    </table>'
 Core = 
 '
        D table data
    '

 -----------------
 >Found Valid Parent
 Target:
 '<table class="possible_target">
              <tr><td>We're targeting this table</td></tr>
     </table>'
 Core = 
 '
              <tr><td>We're targeting this table</td></tr>
     '
```

**Expanded regexes**

```
 # BalancedText_PHP_Html.rxf
 # Processed by  RegexFormat4 (http://www.regexformat.com)

 # '~(?s)<table\s+id="parent">((?<Table_Core>(?:(?>(?:(?!</table\s*>|<table[\s>][^>]*(?<!/)>).)*)|(?<New_Table><table(?!\s+id="parent">)[\s>][^>]*(?<!/)>(?&Table_Core)</table\s*>))*))</table\s*>~'

 (?s)                          # Dot-All

 # Parent Table                                   
 # ==================

 <table \s+ id="parent">       # Parent table start
 (                             # (1 start), Core Start

      (?<Table_Core>                # (2 start), Table Core
           (?:
                (?>
                     (?:
                          (?!                           # Not start/end of another table
                               </table \s* >
                            |  
                               <table [\s>] [^>]* 
                               (?<! / )
                               >
                          )
                          . 
                     )*
                )
             |  
                (?<New_Table>                 # (3 start), New Table                    
                     <table                        # Table start
                     (?! \s+ id="parent"> )        # but, not a parent table type
                     [\s>] [^>]* 
                     (?<! / )
                     >
                     (?&Table_Core)                # Recurse Table Core
                     </table \s* >                 # Table end
                )                             # (3 end)
           )*
      )                             # (2 end)


 )                             # (1 end), Core End
 </table \s* >                 # Parent table end


 # ==========================================================================

 (?s)                                   # Dot-All

 # Target Table                                   
 # ==================

 <table \s+ class="possible_target">    # Target table start
 (                                      # (1 start), Core Start
      (?<Table_Core>                         # (2 start), Table Core
           (?:
                (?>
                     (?:
                          (?!                                    # Not start/end of another table
                               </table \s* >
                            |  
                               <table [\s>] [^>]* 
                               (?<! / )
                               >
                          )
                          . 
                     )*
                )
             |  
                (?<New_Table>                          # (3 start), New Table                    
                     <table                                 # Table start
                     (?! \s+ class="possible_target"> )     # but, not a target table type
                     [\s>] [^>]* 
                     (?<! / )
                     >
                     (?&Table_Core)                         # Recurse Table Core
                     </table \s* >                          # Table end
                )                                      # (3 end)
           )*
      )                                      # (2 end)
 )                                      # (1 end), Core End
 </table \s* >                          # Target table end
```